# IE file upload issue

Tags: internet-explorer, file-upload

I have looked around and still haven't found any answers...I have an input form containing  Picture, Name, Location, bio.. and when I click submit in IE,it sends the text data to the DB but doesn't send the file. Here is the code:

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input type="file" id="mypicture" name="mypicture" />
```

PLEASE WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING ON IE,and why would a company make a product that gives programmers stress. This doesn't happen on other browsers.

Comment: I'm sorry to break the news to you... IE is diseased with regards to file input behavior.

Comment: did you ever manage to fix this beast?

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify a few things?

What do you mean by sending the text data to the DB? Are you trying to store binary files in your DB? I assume you mean the server, are FF/Chrome working fine? What do you get when you var_dump your $_FILES?

If it really is IE only, there are issues with nested forms in IE and not Chrome etc...

And calm down, we all have our gripes with IE8 - it's something you need to learn to live with :P